# Laravel 8 upgrade, Undefined Property $app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a rather advanced application, which I was upgrading from Laravel 6 to Laravel 7 to Laravel 8.

The application is an e-commerce application, and supports various shipping providers.

config/app.php has the following line:

```
App\Services\Shipments\ShippingServiceProvider::class,
```

That file, in the register method has:

```
$this->app->singleton(ShipmentManager::class, function ($app) {

    return new ShipmentManager($app);
});
```

then I get the following error,

```
Undefined property: App\Services\Shipments\ShipmentManager::$app
```

The relevant lines in the file are:

```
return (new ShipmentSender(
    $this,
    $this->app->make(Bus::class),
    $this->app->make(Dispatcher::class))
)->ship($shipment);
```

Comment: It seems inside the ShipmentManager I had to replace this->app with this->container https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#manager-app-property

Answer (score 0):

It seems inside the ShipmentManager I had to replace
`this->app`
with
`this->container`
laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#manager-app-property